# Domain entity with dynamic parent entity

Tags: domain-driven-design

EntityA is an aggregate root and is having many EntityB entities. EntityB is having many EntityC entities. EntityC is referencing back both EntityB (original parent) and EntityA (null when EntityC is created).

At one point I want to set EntityA as a "new parent" of EntityC, so in EntityC I would set the reference to original EntityB parent to null, and would set the reference to EntityA (was null previously).

Is this "dynamic entity parent" idea compatible with DDD?

Comment: Does the business process requires this?

Comment: Not really, I personally don't like it and I would do it differently. We are just having a discussion if it's a correct thing to do in DDD. I don't think it's a right think to do. But I'm happy to be persuaded otherwise.

Comment: If it doesn't require it then don't do it :) It seems very ugly. THe beauty with DDD is that the domain drives the modelling so you don't have to come up with stuff just because it might be useful in the future or whatever design pattern said so

Answer (score 0):

One of the central considerations when designing an aggregate is to regard it as a consistency boundary. So when you're thinking about whether various relationships between constituent entities should be expressed, consider whether these relationships are required to implement behaviors and whether they are required to remain consistent after execution of said behavior. DDD doesn't dictate the implementation of the object model itself so much as it dictates the focus on behavior and transactional consistency. Also many times, relationships are implemented to support a query scenario. In these cases, instead of polluting the aggregate, create a separate [read-model](http://gorodinski.com/blog/2012/04/25/read-models-as-a-tactical-pattern-in-domain-driven-design-ddd/). Also, take a look at [effective aggregate design](https://vaughnvernon.co/?p=139).

Answer (score 0):

Your idea is definitely compatible with DDD.  However, how you go about implementing it is important.

As eulerfx has pointed out the aggregate design is relevant here.  I do suspect, though, that you may have some form of classification structure.  This means that the representation of that structure may become a new set of entities / aggregates.  Or, if not a full blown sub-domain, then maybe have the classification represented by value objects in the entities.  But references to other aggregates within an aggregate is a bit of a red flag should you find yourself in that position.

Comment: Basically EntityA is an Item, EntityB is an ItemVersion, and EntityC is SomethingBelongingToItemVersion. So, item data are versioned, and at one point after one operation SomethingBelongingToItemVersion can no longer be versioned, and will be fixed directly on Item to express that it won't be versioned anymore